# How to create blogs Like Button in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a blog system. Everything is going well, user can also comment on blogs.
But problem is that I want create a Blog Like button by which user can like blog.
Here is my code:
**My EJS file**

```
 <%= data.likes.length%></span> <a class="like" id="like">Likes</a>

<script>
        function likeFn(){
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url:"http://localhost:3000/like/<%= data.id%>",
            success:function(data){
            alert('success');
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus,err)
            {
            alert("err");
                }
            });};
            $("#like").on('click', function(){
            likeFn();
            });
        </script>
```

and in my **index.js**

```
router.post('/like/:id', function(req, res,next){
  blogModel.update({_id:req.params.id},{$push:{likes:req.user.id}}, function(err, data){
          if(err){res.json(err)}
          else{console.log('liked by'+ req.user.name)
     }
   });
    });
```

**DB schema**

```
var blogSchema=new Schema({
    title:String,
    description:String,
    tags:String,
    status:{type:String, default:'pending'},
    img:{type:String},
    comments:[{comment:String, commentdate:Date, commentby:String}],
    likes:[{type:String}],
    postedby:String,
    date:Date
    });
```

Problem is that when first user click on like button, that loggedin user's Id updates in DB, when second user click on like button so the new user id overwrite previous one. 
I am not able to create an array of all the users who click on like button.

Comment: Your query seems fine only. I have tried and it is working properly. Is there any error you are getting?

Comment: there is no any error, its seems like array is not creating when more than 1 user click on like button. I meant, when second user click on button its updates previous one

Comment: yeah.... I don't know how its start working.... I didn't change any single line of code. Now its working good but its showing wrong alert msg of error from `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus,err)
            {
            alert("err");
                }`

Comment: Console the error and check. What is the error.

Comment: I removed alert from `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus,err) {}` now its not showing  any alert msg. Now one thing to know that after clicking on like button no. of likes is not changing, its changing when I refresh my page, it seems like that ajax is not working. Can you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: May be you should ask one more question regarding the issue you mentioned and close this question.